# Is there a way to add pages after a footer in RDLC?

Tags: report, rdlc

I have a footer, and a rectangle, which contains textboxes for terms and conditions. It's visibility is based on a conditional. The problem is that the terms and conditions take up more than 1 page, so they get cut off. Is there a way to add additional pages after a footer?

Here's the visibility code with the conditional :

```
=IIf(First(Fields!IsUSA.Value, "PurchaseOrder"), false, true)
Or IIf(Globals!PageNumber=Globals!OverallTotalPages, false, true)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could place the terms and conditions onto a rectangle (or multiple rectangles) and play with the size so they fit a new page perfectly.
The `PageBreak` properties can be of use here.

Simply place this rectangle at the very bottom of your report body (not the the page footer).
If you place it at the very bottom this will always be on the last page of the document. So you don't need an expression to have it appear only at the end.
However, you could define an expression for the `Visibility` property of the rectangle if you wish to have more control over it. So you can hide it based on a parameter value instead of having to create another second report without them.

If you sized the rectangle correctly and defined the right `BreakLocation` you should be able to get the desired behavior.